# Use an object-literal as array item

Tags: javascript

I have an object-literal like this

```
var data = {name:'racheal', class:'jss2', town:'kaduna'}
```

I would love this to be in an array like this

```
[{name:'racheal', class:'jss2', town:'kaduna'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just create an array with it:

```
var obj = {name:'racheal', class:'jss2', town:'kaduna'}

var arr = [obj];
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple use of the `push` method on an array will achieve this:

```
var myObj = {name:'racheal', class:'jss2', town:'kaduna'};
var myArray = [];
myArray.push(myObj);
```

Or, as Tushar says in comments, you can simply initialise a new array with the Object in it:

```
var myObj = {name:'racheal', class:'jss2', town:'kaduna'};    
var myArray = [myObj];
```

You can read a bit more on Arrays and their various methods and how to use them here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array